# How do I switch my play button to a pause button in Swift?

Tags: swift

working on my first stopwatch app.

I currently have a play button, pause button, and stop button.

I'd like to combine the play and pause button so that they switch back and forth.

My code looks like this:

```
var timer = NSTimer()

var count = 0

func updateTime() {

    count++

    time.text = "\(count)"


}

@IBAction func pauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

}

@IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!

@IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

    count = 0

    time.text = "0"

}

@IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding booleans. See my code below.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var time = NSTimer()
    var count = 0

    var running = false

    func result (){

        count++
        label.text = String(count)
        println(count)

    }

    @IBAction func playpause(sender: AnyObject) {

        if running == false {

            time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            running = true }

        else {

            time.invalidate()

            running = false

        }



    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a variable bound to the button, something like this:

```
@IBOutlet var thePlayPauseButton : UIButton!
```

This button will be linked with some action:

```
@IBAction func togglePlayPauseButton (button: UIButton) {
  // If we are 'paused', then play:
  if button.titleLabel!.text == "Pause" {
    button.titleLabel!.text = "Play"
    // do actual play ...
   timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval (1, 
       target: self, 
       selector: Selector("updateTime"), 
       userInfo: nil, 
       repeats: true)
  }
  else if button.titleLabel!.text == "Play" {
    button.titleLabel!.text = "Pause"
    // do actual pause ...
    timer.invalidate()
  }
  else { /* error */ }
}
```

Of course, structurally you can use a `switch//case` and you can perform the toggle behavior by calling your preexisting `pause` and `play` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is somewhat dated, but I was working with the same problem and I came up with a slightly different answer and wanted to share it to help others. Here is what I came up with in toggling the pause and play buttons.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var time = NSTimer()
var seconds = 0
var running = false

func timer() {
    seconds++
    timeLabel.text = "\(seconds)"
}

func playing() {
    time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    running = true
}

func pausing() {
    time.invalidate()
    running = false
}

@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    time.invalidate()
    seconds = 0
    timeLabel.text = "0"
}
@IBAction func pausePlayToggleButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if running == false {
        return playing()
    } else {
        return pausing()
    }
}
```

I had both a pause and play button and I essentially took their effects and placed them in functions and used them as return values for a single button.